# Celsius to Fahrenheit formula to calculate range of temperatures

Tags: algebra-precalculus, dimensional-analysis

Let's assume the maximum temperature during a month is $86 F ^\circ$ of all days and the minimum temperature during a month of all days is $74 F ^ \circ $. The range of temperature is the difference of the two, so $12 F ^\circ$.

The formula for the temperature is $$C=\frac{5}{9}(F-32)$$.

Why isn't the corresponding range of temperature in that particular month in centigrade

$$C=\frac{5}{9}(12-32)$$

but rather around

$$7 C ^\circ$$?

Comment: A convenient numerical example of this: Farenheit and Celsius both agree at -40 degrees. But 0 degrees Celsius is 32 degrees Farenheit, so the range of Celsius is 40 degrees whereas for Farenheit it's 72. (Which, suggestively, is a 5:9 ratio...)

Comment: Assume that you and your friend are measuring elevations of locations. You use sea level as zero, but your friend prefers to use the town square, 100 meters above sealevel, as the baseline. So if your friend says elevation $x$, you mentally add $100$ to the figure. Your friend then tells you that your dorm is 5 meter above the town square, and your favorite pub is two meters above the town square - an elevation difference of 3 meters. By the logic of your question you would claim that the elevation difference between the dorm and the pub is 103 meters. Surely you see that is absurd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That because the difference of two values of an *affine function*  is the value of the *associated linear map* at the difference.

In formula:
$$\bigl(a(x+\Delta x)+b\bigr)-(ax+b)=a\mkern 2mu\Delta x, \quad\text{not }\; a\mkern 2mu\Delta x+b.$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the two temperatures in F are $F_1$ and $F_2$. Then $F_1$ in C, which we call $C_1$, is given by
$$ C_1 = \frac{5}{9}(F_1-32), $$
and likewise,
$$ C_2 = \frac{5}{9}(F_2-32). $$
Then the difference between $C_1$ and $C_2$ is
$$ C_1-C_2 = \frac{5}{9}(F_1-32) - \frac{5}{9}(F_2-32) = \frac{5}{9}(F_1-F_2) : $$
the 32 terms cancel out, because it is the same shift applied to both. (It's the same if you measured on a ruler starting from $1$ instead of $0$: the difference between two measurements would be the same, even though they are both $1$ larger than measuring from the beginning.)

Comment: Another way to say it: A change of 9 degrees Farenheit is equivalent to a change of 5 degrees Celsius, so one degree Celsius is nearly twice as big as one degree Farenheit. (Hence why a moderate change in Celsius temperature corresponds to a significant change in Farenheit temperature.)